# How to draw segment with round end that does NOT extend beyond values

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I am somewhat surprised that this has never caught my attention (I guess I've never drawn much with round line ends until today).

When drawing a segment with round line end, this is "of course" added as additional grob element, but it's adding "value" to the graphical representation by extending beyond the given values. How could I change this?

I think one would need re-calculate the original values so that it will be reaching the correct value when adding the round end, but this would require this calculation at draw time, i.e. within the grob function. And I'm very bad with grobs. Help would be appreciated.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 0)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, 1), lty = 2) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               linewidth = 6, alpha = .5, 
               lineend = "round")  +
  labs(title =  "NOT an accurate representation of the data",
       caption = "The line extends beyond the given values")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is deceptively difficult. The most foolproof way of doing it is to define a new `makeContent` method for a `segmentsGrob`, which in turn means defining a new grob class, which has to be called from a new `Geom` class, which requires a new `geom`. The maths itself isn't too difficult, but there's a lot of boilerplate involved.

First, let us define the function that actually does the maths on the modified `segmentsGrob`, which will just be a `segmentsGrob` with a different S3 class name - we'll call it `"roundseg"`:

```r
makeContent.roundseg <- function(x) {
  x$x0 <- grid::convertX(x$x0, "cm")
  x$x1 <- grid::convertX(x$x1, "cm")
  x$y0 <- grid::convertY(x$y0, "cm")
  x$y1 <- grid::convertY(x$y1, "cm")
  xmin <- pmin(as.numeric(x$x0), as.numeric(x$x1))
  xmax <- pmax(as.numeric(x$x0), as.numeric(x$x1))
  ymin <- pmin(as.numeric(x$y0), as.numeric(x$y1))
  ymax <- pmax(as.numeric(x$y0), as.numeric(x$y1))
  theta <- atan2(ymax - ymin, xmax - xmin)
  size <- 0.5 * x$gp$lwd / .stroke
  xmin <- xmin + cos(theta) * size
  xmax <- xmax - cos(theta) * size
  ymin <- ymin + sin(theta) * size
  ymax <- ymax - sin(theta) * size
  x$x0 <- unit(xmin, "cm")
  x$x1 <- unit(xmax, "cm")
  x$y0 <- unit(ymin, "cm")
  x$y1 <- unit(ymax, "cm")
  return(x)
}
```

Now we define a new `Geom` class - we'll call it `GeomRoundseg`. It's almost identical to `GeomSegment`, except its `draw_panel` member is redefined to change the `segmentsGrob` to a different class, so that the above function is called whenever the grob is drawn or the window resized:

```r
GeomRoundseg <- ggproto("GeomRoundseg", GeomSegment,
  draw_panel = function (self, data, panel_params, coord, arrow = NULL, 
                         arrow.fill = NULL, linejoin = "round", na.rm = FALSE) 
{
  data <- ggplot2:::check_linewidth(data, snake_class(self))
  data <- ggplot2:::remove_missing(data, na.rm = na.rm, c("x", "y", "xend", 
                        "yend", "linetype", "linewidth", "shape"), 
                        name = "geom_roundseg")
  if (ggplot2:::empty(data)) 
    return(zeroGrob())
  if (coord$is_linear()) {
    coord <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    arrow.fill <- ggplot2:::`%||%`(arrow.fill, coord$colour)
    sg <- grid::segmentsGrob(coord$x, coord$y, coord$xend, coord$yend, 
              default.units = "native", 
              gp = grid::gpar(col = scales::alpha(coord$colour, 
              coord$alpha), fill = scales::alpha(arrow.fill, coord$alpha), 
              lwd = coord$linewidth * .pt, lty = coord$linetype, 
              lineend = "round", linejoin = linejoin), arrow = arrow)
    class(sg) <- c("roundseg", class(sg))
    return(sg)
  }
  data$group <- 1:nrow(data)
  starts <- subset(data, select = c(-xend, -yend))
  ends <- rename(subset(data, select = c(-x, -y)), c(xend = "x", 
                                                     yend = "y"))
  pieces <- vec_rbind0(starts, ends)
  pieces <- pieces[order(pieces$group), ]
  GeomPath$draw_panel(pieces, panel_params, coord, arrow = arrow, 
                      lineend = lineend)
})
```

Finally, we need a `geom_roundseg` function that is almost an exact copy of `geom_segment`, except its `lineend` parameter is removed and it uses our new Geom object:

```r
geom_roundseg <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
          position = "identity", ..., arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, 
          linejoin = "round", na.rm = FALSE, 
          show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomRoundseg, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, 
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = rlang::list2(arrow = arrow, arrow.fill = arrow.fill, 
                       linejoin = linejoin, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
```

Now we're done. When we call our plot, the tips of the rounded segment will be at the specified x, y co-ordinates:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 0)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(0, 1), lty = 2) +
  geom_roundseg(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               linewidth = 6, alpha = 0.5)  +
  labs(title =  "Now an accurate representation of the data",
       caption = "The line meets the given values")
```

[image]

If we rescale the window, the tips stay in place:

[image]

And changing the linewidth is catered for:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 0)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_roundseg(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               linewidth = 30, alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend))
```

[image]

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 0)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_roundseg(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend))
```

[image]

And this continues to work whatever the angle of our segment:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 0, xend = 1, y = 0, yend = 1)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_roundseg(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               linewidth = 6, alpha = 0.5)  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(xend, yend))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant Allan! Very impressive!!

Comment: FWIW I've packaged this wonderful geom into the not quite stable package [ggtrail](https://github.com/tjebo/ggtrail) - only on GitHub. I've no idea why, but I had to change `unit = "cm"` to `unit = "points"` in all instances in the makeContent function, and instead of a constant of 0.5 for the size, I had to use `sqrt(2)`

Comment: Very nice @tjebo. This is a useful addition to the ggplot ecosystem (especially geom_colorpath). Any plans to get it on CRAN?

Comment: I should add a disclaimer that the mechanism needs a couple of tweaks to make it robust. Firstly, the mechanism I used sorts the segment ends from left to right and bottom to top, so the direction of the segment will not always be the intended one. This is only important if one is drawing arrows on the segments, but I feel that this would need to be handled better in a production-level geom. Secondly, some co-ordinate transforms turn segments into paths, and this isn't handled here either (it reverts to standard behaviour with non-linear co-ordinate systems). This would need fixed too.

Comment: Thanks :) [Teun wasn't so convinced about the use case of geom_colorpath](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggh4x/issues/70) :D But I guess it was more in the context of ggh4x. Not sure about getting ggtrail CRAN ready though. My knowledge of ggplot objects is still rather rudimentary and I have other stuff on my plate  at the moment. These are also important things you have said and I would probably not directly know how to solve them.

Comment: I needed this for paths as well and 'deceptively difficult' sure does justice to the problem!

Comment: @teunbrand did you solve it? I can see a way to do it, but it would be imperfect in situations where the line kinks sharply near the end of the path. I don't know how much that would be a problem in real use cases, but even thinking of those edge cases puts me off attempting an implementation.

Comment: The way I did it was (1) for all points on path calculate distance to end of the path, (2) run-length encode where distance is less than how much you want to shorten and (4) only trim the last run ((5) interpolate new point at the shortening distance). Code is [here](https://github.com/teunbrand/ggarrow/blob/main/R/drawing_line_resection.R) if you're curious.

Comment: Very nice @teunbrand. Love the code layout too.